# Ubuntu 22.04: Add menu items to the Gnome Desktop context menu

Tags: gnome, python, nautilus, menu

Recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 (my first foray into Linux).

One thing I got involved with from the get-go was adding custom entries to the context menus. Basically, using `python3-nautilus`, I managed to add menu items to context menus of folders (via `get_background_items`) and files (via `get_file_items`). For files, I could even add the custom entries for all files or specific file types by filtering `mime-types`.
So far so good.

What I haven't been able to figure out was how to add items to the Gnome Desktop context menu. I presume the Gnome Desktop is closely tied to the Nautilus file manager but I have no idea how to go about customizing the Desktop context menu using `python-nautilus`.

Any help please?

EDIT:
For example, the right click context menu for folder backgrounds (empty space in a folder window) now has two additional custom items, Calculator and Text Editor, that allow me to launch those apps from within the context menu. I would like to achieve the same thing (or at least something in the same vein) for the desktop right click menu.

[image]

To further explain how the above customization was achieved, first, I installed `python3-nautilus`, and then I created a `Python` script (well, I actually created several scripts for different functionality) in the `Home/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions` folder with the following code:

```
import os

from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject

class BackgroundItemMenuProvider(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def menu_activate_cb_gcalc(self, menu, file):
         os.system("gnome-calculator & pid=$!")
         
    def menu_activate_cb_gedit(self, menu, file):
         os.system("gnome-text-editor --new-window & pid=$!")

    def get_background_items(self, window, file):
        item_gcalc = Nautilus.MenuItem(name='BackgroundItemMenuProvider::Calculator', 
                                       label='Calculator', 
                                       tip='',
                                       icon='')
        item_gcalc.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb_gcalc, file)
        item_gedit = Nautilus.MenuItem(name='BackgroundItemMenuProvider::TextEditor', 
                                       label='Text Editor', 
                                       tip='',
                                       icon='')
        item_gedit.connect('activate', self.menu_activate_cb_gedit, file)
        return item_gcalc,item_gedit,
```

Comment: @24601 the question is about adding custom items to Nautlis' context menu (When you right-click on file). OP managed to do it for folders and normal files, but can't figure out how to do it for on the desktop, as in when right-clicking on empty space on your desktop.

Comment: @Dan the OP edited and added further info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shell extension like [desktopicons-neo](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4337/desktop-icons-neo/) which integrates nautilus into the desktop. Then your custom context options will work on the desktop also. Keep in mind that running a file manager on the desktop can be buggy or laggy at times (especially with too many context menu options).

Comment: Do you have references as to why it is buggy and laggy?